# Get next set of result from a SQL procedure call with Symfony 1.4 & Doctrine

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, doctrine, symfony-1.4

Within my symfony application, I'm executing a SQL store procedure that returns me 3 sets of result, the first one contains one "nb" column, the second "nb_previous", and the third "nb_not_done".

I was thinking of using the fetchAll method, but it only returns me the first set of result (so I only get the "nb" value).

Here's my code so far :

```
 $con = Doctrine_Manager::connection();
 $stmt = $con->prepare('CALL pStatReportingVisit(\''. $begining_date .'\', \''. $end_date .' 23:55\', \''. $user_id .'\', true);'); 
 $ret = $stmt->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
 $res = $stmt->fetchAll();
 var_dump($res);
```

So the output only gives me :

```
 array(1) {
    [0]=>array(2) {
         ["nb"] => string(1) "2"
         [0] => string(1) "2"
    }
 }
```

How can I access the next sets of results ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. For the ones interested, there's one undocumented function that you can call, which is nextRowset();